# What's the keycode of the square brackets

Tags: java, keyevent, keycode

I'm trying to use the Robot class in Java and type some text. Unfortunately I'm having problems finding the key codes of the square brackets, this symbol `|` and this symbol  `. I can't find them in the KeyEvent constants. I want to use them, because the text i'm typing is in cyrillic and these symbols represent characters in the alphabet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: "|" is called *pipe* and "`" - *backtick*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) for `KeyEvent`

`KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET`

and

`KeyEvent.VK_CLOSE_BRACKET`

**Edit**

From the `KeyEvent` JavaDoc

> This low-level event is generated by a component object (such as a
>   text field) when a key is pressed, released, or typed.

So on a US 101-key keyboard, the <kbd>`</kbd> and <kbd>~</kbd> will produce the same keycode, although <kbd>~</kbd> will have a <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> modifier.  Also notice that `KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH` traps the <kbd>|</kbd> (pipe) keystroke too.

Try adding the following sample `KeyAdapter` to your project to see this in action.

```
new KeyAdapter()
{
    public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE)
        {
            e.toString();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH)
        {
            e.toString();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET)
        {
            e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general solution is to call [`KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(int c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getExtendedKeyCodeForChar%28int%29).  If the unicode codepoint `c` has a `VK_` constant that will be returned.  Otherwise a "unique integer" is returned.

I think that '`' is KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE ...