# What's the KeyEvent for pipe? (|)

Tags: java, pipe, keyevent

What's the KeyEvent for pipe? I mean this key - '|'.

I'm using java.awt.Robot.keyPress and I can't find a way to send send '|'.

The KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362927/whats-the-keycode-of-the-square-brackets) in a different question is not doing it.

Couldn't find it.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the keycode of the square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362927/whats-the-keycode-of-the-square-brackets)

Comment: So, is it VK_BACK_SLASH?

Comment: Yes, and combined with the Shift modifier.

Comment: @4castle So on a keyboard with german layout it would be VK_LESS with the VK_ALT_GRAPH modifier?

Comment: Yes. These comments are very layout-specific. US, German, French, and other keyboards all have the `|` on a different key.

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19850562/8473028

Comment: @GyroGearless I don't know, but `KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar('|')` should give the right output if they're just trying to call java.awt.Robot.keyPress.

Comment: KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar('|') returns some big number and it's not pressing '|' on my computer.